# std class object array

Tags: stdclass

I am getting this array of std class object how can i call it in single array as you can see only some values are changed.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [movie_id] => 4
            [movie_name] => Harvey
            [genre_id] => 4
            [genre_title] => Action/Adventure
            [rating_id] => 2
            [rating_title] => Pg-16 (USA)
            [person_id] => 14
            [person_name] => John Beck
            [role_title] => producer
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [movie_id] => 4
            [movie_name] => Harvey
            [genre_id] => 4
            [genre_title] => Action/Adventure
            [rating_id] => 2
            [rating_title] => Pg-16 (USA)
            [person_id] => 15
            [person_name] => Henry Koster
            [role_title] => directer
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [movie_id] => 4
            [movie_name] => Harvey
            [genre_id] => 4
            [genre_title] => Action/Adventure
            [rating_id] => 2
            [rating_title] => Pg-16 (USA)
            [person_id] => 16
            [person_name] => Mary Coyle Chase
            [role_title] => writer
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [movie_id] => 4
            [movie_name] => Harvey
            [genre_id] => 4
            [genre_title] => Action/Adventure
            [rating_id] => 2
            [rating_title] => Pg-16 (USA)
            [person_id] => 17
            [person_name] => Oscar Brodney
            [role_title] => writer
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [movie_id] => 4
            [movie_name] => Harvey
            [genre_id] => 4
            [genre_title] => Action/Adventure
            [rating_id] => 2
            [rating_title] => Pg-16 (USA)
            [person_id] => 18
            [person_name] => Myles Connolly
            [role_title] => writer
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't understand. Is it a statement, question or multiple sentences?

Comment: its a question i am asking is it posible to get all of them in one array

Comment: It's a question **dot** I am asking **if** it is possible to get all of them in one array **dot**

Comment: please help, i am in problem

Comment: Are you trying to get `person_id`, `person_name` and `role_title` from **each** object to **one** array of all the values or array of array of values?

Comment: yes i want to get all fields in one array.Then i want to encode that array into json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what are you trying to achieve. To print only some members try doing this:

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {

    echo '<pre>';
    echo $value->person_id . " ";
    echo $value->person_name . " ";
    echo $value->role_title . " ";
    echo "\n";
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

And if you can print it, you can save it to new array however you desire.

Comment: I think there is problem in my array

Comment: You have array of objects. You can acces each object by `array[index]`. You can acces object's members by `object->member`. Altogether it is something like this: `array[0]->member`. That's what the foreach do. You can then save those values into new array and convert that array.

Comment: How to save this in array i am new to php

Comment: Saving old values into new array `$newarray["key"] = $oldarray[object_index]->member;` But you probably want this: make a new Array of Arrays `$newarray["person1"]["person_id"] = $oldarray[0]->person_id;` etc. Try googling a bit, use php.net.

Comment: is it possible to combine these array

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => Samuel Goldwyn
    [2] => producer 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2 
    [1] => George Fitzmaurice
    [2] => directer 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3 
    [1] => Dorothy Arzner
    [2] => directer 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4 
    [1] => Alex Merces
    [2] => writer 
)

Comment: Sure. Try googling "php join arrays" and it will find `array_merge` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php But you have same keys, which is a problem. Save it into array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
echo '<pre>';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $newarray[$key]["person_id"]   = $value->person_id;
    $newarray[$key]["person_name"] = $value->person_name;
    $newarray[$key]["role_title"]  = $value->role_title;
}

// var_dump($newarray);
$json = json_encode($newarray);
echo $json;

echo "</pre>";
```

You should read some tutorials. These are real basics.

Comment: it result in this                                     [{"person_id":"1","person_name":"Samuel Goldwyn","role_title":"producer"},{"person_id":"2","person_name":"George Fitzmaurice","role_title":"directer"},{"person_id":"3","person_name":"Dorothy Arzner","role_title":"directer"},{"person_id":"4","person_name":"Alex Merces","role_title":"writer"}]